# Does anyone knowhow to set a live magento site to the local one?

Tags: magento, localhost, live

I'm a beginner to a magento. Kindly help me I'm stuck with this.I have source files and database. But I don't know how to setup.

Answer (score 2):

These steps will help you:

1.Download the code base.

2.Download the database.

3.Import the database to the mysql

4.Put the code to the server webroot from where I can execute it using browser for e.g I am using wampserver on windows 7 so I put code into the 
`C:\wamp\www\local dir`.

5.First remove all the folders and files from the webroot/var/cache/ directory

6.Backup your local.xml file and delete the local.xml file from webroot/app/etc/ directory

7.Then from the browser access the url for the local site, for e.g mine would be `http://localhost/localmagento/`, Magento will automatically start the installation process, where you need to provide new login details for admin and your local site URL etc, for your local environment.

You can refer to Magento official [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/).

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, Thank you very much for your reply. I follow above steps.But I coudn't find the local.xml file in app/etc. Only have below files                          config.php
di.xml
env.php
NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
vendor_path.php                         Do I need to create local.xml file?

Comment: Which version of magento you are using??

Comment: I'm using Magento 2 version

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have the source and database files.
**For Magento 1**

So you have the source file and database right then
 if you use  the lampp server in ubuntu then follw the steps below.

1) we can put the source file in your localhost project root folder
2) via terminal you can import the database for that

2a)create a database  for eg: "magento1_local"

2b)go to the  run the command

**mysql -u username -p magento1_local <  dbfile.sql**

enter mysql password if you set for localhost

**3)After successful import of database you need to change base_url in the table "core_config"**

4)change config settings in the file app/etc/local.xml (change database  credentials)

5)check and give permission for the folder var/ , media/ app/etc

**For Magento 2**

So you have the source file and database right then

1) we can put the source file in your localhost project root folder

2) via terminal you can import the database for that

2a)create a database  for eg: "magento2_local"

2b)go to the  run the command

**mysql -u username -p magento_local2 <  dbfile.sql**

enter mysql password if you set for localhost

**3)After successful import of database you need to change base_url in the table "core_config"**

4)change config settings in the file app/etc/env.php (change database  credentials)

5)check and give permission for the folder var/ , pub/ app/etc
and run the below commands

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod 777 -R var/ pub/media pub/static
```